# npm test - Must use import to load ES Module - but I thought I was? (node 12)

Tags: npm, mocha.js, es6-module-loader

My files are all `.mjs` extension

I have  `fizz_buzz.mjs` and `test/fizz_buzz.spec.mjs`

`test/fizz_buzz.spec.mjs` uses

```
import { fizzBuzz } from '../fizz_buzz'
```

I run `npm test` and I get

```
> mocha test/**/*.spec.mjs                                                                                                                              

/home/durrantm/Dropbox/90_2019/work/code/js/mocha_chai_bdd_tdd_exercises/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1163                                               
      else throw err                                                                                                                                    
           ^                                                                                                                                            

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /home/durrantm/Dropbox/90_2019/work/code/js/mocha_chai_bdd_tdd_exercises/test/fizz_buzz.spec
.mjs                                                                                                                                                    
    at Object.Module._extensions..mjs (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:9)                                                                          
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
```

`fizz_buzz.mjs` currently just has:

```
$ cat fizz_buzz.mjs 
export function fizzBuzz() {
  return true
}
```

---

fyi `package .json` uses

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha test/**/*.spec.mjs"
},
```

in case that is the issue ?

I also tried `$ mocha test/**/*.spec.mjs --experimental-modules` at the command line but same error

Comment: Consider trying the [v7.0.0-esm1](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/releases/tag/v7.0.0-esm1) release of `mocha` that was published to npm registry approx one week ago. It's description states _"Enables Mocha to load ECMAScript Modules test files"_ Note: It's a _"experimental"_ release and running `npm show mocha dist-tags.latest` reveals that `7.0.0` remains as the `latest` stable version.