# How can I use modules with mocha ? My mjs files get an error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

With commonjs and using `require()` for .js files and a command of

```
mocha `**/*.spec.js`
```

Files:

```
capitalize.js
test/capitalize.js
```

my tests run

Output:

```
mocha
Capitalize sentences
✓ calls the function
✓ calls the function
✓ calls the function
✓ Works for a second sentence
✓ Handles 3 dots
✓ Handles existing capitalization dots
✓ Preserves existing last dot
✓ Preserves carriage returns ("\n")
```

I want to use ES6 modules. So I:

- changed both file extensions to `.js from .mjs
- changed file I an running (the test) from

  ```
  export function capitalize(paragraph) {
  ```

  to

  ```
  exports.capitalize = function(paragraph) {
  ```
- changed file I include from

  ```
  export function capitalize(paragraph) {
  ```

  to

  ```
  exports.capitalize = function(paragraph) {
  ```

However, mocha isn't recognizing my tests and I get

```
Error: No test files found: "**/*.spec.js"
```

// Not too surprising given I changed the file extensions

If I now changed `package.json` from

```
"test": "mocha **/*.spec.js"
```

to

```
"test": "mocha **/*.spec.mjs"
```

I get

$ mocha
Error: No test files found

from mocha directly, or with `npm test` I get

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:
```

How to fix?

Comment: How do you import other modules into your project?

Comment: Which version of mocha are you using? Is it [v7.0.0-esm1](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/releases/tag/v7.0.0-esm1). as mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59803401/npm-test-must-use-import-to-load-es-module-but-i-thought-i-was-node-12#comment-105759358) to your other question which shows a same error. In issue [#3006](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/3006) it seems that ESM modules are not supported in mocha stable releases/versions - only supported in _v7.0.0-esm (experimental)_ release.